# [FAILED]Failed to start dbus.service - D-bus System message Bus

Tags: boot, error-handling

I don't know how it happened, but this is appearing on my screen when I try to boot Ubuntu from the GRUB menu.
I have dual booted Windows 10 and Ubuntu.
It was working just fine yesterday.
Although just before closing, the battery suddenly went from 100% to 0%, but it was still running( It was still showing battery to be 0% though, which I think was an error)
I ignored it at that time, but now it's not even opening.
I will we grateful if you could help me.
[image]